# SQL query select multiple rows where 'field' equals to 'value' then add the other ids associated with the result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `users` table that contains persons and their status. The ID field is not unique.

```
ID | Name | Status
1  | Jon  | Online
2  | Ken  | Away
3  | Kim  | Online
4  | Van  | Offline
1  | Jon  | NULL
2  | Ken  | NULL
3  | Kim  | NULL
4  | Van  | NULL
1  | Jon  | Online
```

In this case, I want to get the Users that are online and all the other same ids of the user in this table to form like this.

```
ID | Name | Status
1  | Jon  | Online
1  | Jon  | Online
1  | Jon  | NULL
3  | Kim  | Online
3  | Kim  | NULL
```

Is there a way to get this result with one select statement?

Comment: What version and type of SQL?

Comment: And is there a date or time associated with that Online value? Otherwise, as you can see with ID1 is Jon Online or not?

Comment: @Shawn oracle 10.2. Yes there is a date associated, I only simplified it into these 3 fields.

Comment: `the Users that are online` - if there are multiple records per user in the status table, how does one know that the user is actually on-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this -- one is to use `exists`:

```
select id, name, status
from users u
where exists (
    select 1
    from users u2 
    where u.id = u2.id and u2.status = 'Online'
    )
```

---

Here's a version using `in` (although I prefer the prior):

```
select id, name, status
from users
where id in (
    select id
    from users 
    where status = 'Online'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a login timestamp, it doesn't give you much information of how you want to get the most recent event for a person. If they can have 3 rows, how do you know which one means they ARE online and which one means they WERE online.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3833e/4 <<< MS SQL Setup

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f190f/2 <<< Oracle SQL Setup

The Fiddle gives you the people in descending order of most recent login grouped by person. If you only want to grab the most recent logins, use the second select on the SQL side.

```
SELECT t1.ID
    , t1.Name
    , t1.Status
    , t1.OnlineTimeStamp
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.OnlineTimeStamp DESC ) AS rn
FROM Test_Client t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Test_Client t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Status = 'Online' )
ORDER BY t1.ID, rn

;

SELECT tcSub.ID
    , tcSub.Name
    , tcSub.Status
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID
        , t1.Name
        , t1.Status
        , t1.OnlineTimeStamp
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.OnlineTimeStamp DESC ) AS rn
    FROM Test_Client t1
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Test_Client t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Status = 'Online' )
    ) tcSub
WHERE tcSub.rn = 1
ORDER BY tcSub.ID
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that this was Oracle. Above SQL is MSSQL, but I believe the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION......) syntax works in Oracle as well.

Comment: Why do you want to return the most recent?  I think this is a misunderstanding of the question...

Comment: If this is a definition of whether a person is currently logged in or not, why wouldn't you want their most recent login action? Without context, the query doesn't really provide a lot of information other than the fact that at some point Jon was logged in.

Comment: I guess a Status of "Away" would technically mean that the user is currently logged in also, but I don't know what his login scheme is.

Comment: That's not the question though.  The question is -- if a user has a status of 'Online', return that user and all other records associated with that user (including 'Away' and 'NULL').  `Exists` is the best answer -- Just a misunderstanding...

Comment: I did add the EXISTS to get to that, and I think that's a good way to get associated records, if that's all that's needed. I just went a little further to provide more information for the intent that I could infer from the question.  What if someone has rows for "Online", "Away" and NULL. What's that person's actual Status? That doesn't tell if they are currently logged in. Without ordering the results, the query really doesn't tell you anything, other than if someone logged in at some point.